# Need help printing Fibonacci sequence in aligned columns

Tags: c, fibonacci

I'm currently able to print the sequence but I need it to print in specific format. I need it to print in columns, for instance if I entered 10 as an input the output should look like this:[image]

Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
  int i, num = 0;
  int n;
  long int f1 =1, f2 = 1;
  if ( argc > 1 ) {
    num = atoi( args[1] );    // convert a number string to an integer
    printf("%d\n", num);      // to test if the it get the argument    

    if (1 <= num && num <= 40) {      
        for(i=1;i<10;i++){
            n = f1 + f2;
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = n;
            printf("%d\n",n);
        }
    }
}
   else
       printf("no argument");

    printf("\n");  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please replace the picture of text by text. Please explain the rule of the desired output format. "rows of four numbers each" maybe? Can you describe the difference between the output you achieve and the output you get? Can you do so by describing where undesired newlines occur and where desired newlines are missing? If you can, it sets you up for solving your homework yourself. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: whats that `i < 10` doing there, the picture shows you want 4 values in a row

Comment: Every time you print a number you are using `"%d\n"`, so every time you print the number, it will go to a new line after the number. Any time you don't want a new line, don't use `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

*(This seems to be a homework assignment, so I will answer according to the compromise described here [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) . I.e. I will not provide a full code solution. Instead I will help you thinking in a way which allows you to do your homework yourself, by giving hints.)*

1st Hint:

- Describe the output you achieve.
- Describe the desired output.
- Do so by specifying the position of unwanted newlines and the position where needed newlines are missing.

2nd Hint:

- you need to keep in mind the number of digits needed to represent the numbers
- use that knowledge to get the alignment of e.g. 2 and 13 right
- for that you need (before starting to print) an opinion on how wide a column should be

3rd Hint:

- using `\t` for alignment seems a promising concept
- but it is environment specifically bount to fail for numbers with a certain number of digits
- numbers with 8 digits and more are a problem for alignment by tabulators
  (at least in your environment, in others it might already fail for e.g. 4 digits),
  find the explanation for that
- find a different method to introduce an appropriate number of leading white spaces, depending on how wide the number to print is

Let me know how much this helped, I might give more hints.

Comment: ya an answer provided below works up until the digits get larger like if the input was 40. I'm trying to figure it out at the moment

Comment: Ok so I've fixed everything except one issue, if the number is 8 digits or more the spacing is incorrect. I think this is due to the if statement creating space every 4 digits, therefore when it reaches 8 digits it creates twice the space required. Still working to fix this issue

Comment: Are you referring to the if as in the answer by cleblanc?

Comment: yes specifically this part of the code   if (++i%4==0){
                                                                printf("\n");                                                              
                                                            }

Comment: Have you made up your mind how wide each column should be? For numbers up to eight digits the width of a column should be at least 9, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes 8 digits is the maximum possible so 9 seems suitable. I'm just looking through syntax atm to figure out how to implement it.

Comment: For numbers with 8 digits, the problem cannot come from the line `if (++i%4==0) printf("\n");` the shortsighted use of `\t` is the culprit. Please try and find and decribe the reason why.

Comment: In the description of the assignment, I cannot find a restriction to numbers with at most 8 digits. Is that mentioned outside the part which you have shown? If not please help me by pointing out where the limit is implied.

Comment: if (1 <= num && num <= 40) restricts it to a maximum of 8 possible digits

Comment: I see. But that is part of your implementation, isn't it? Or is that some kind of code template provided by the teacher and therefor practically part of the assignment? In any case, yes that is an appropriate restriction.

Comment: By the way, did you consider the comment by pm100? It seems a misunderstanding about the purpose of the loop, but asking where that 10 comes from is valid. One of your comments seems to indicate that your code does not have a 10 there anymore. What is there now?

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspiciously like homework, so I don't think anyone should **give** you the answer. That being said, you might want to check out the [modulus operator](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html). Hint: Every time `num % something` is equal to `0` you may want to insert a line break.

The other thing you'll want to look at is [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) or [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/). Try `"%20d"` vs `"%-20d"` for example.

Good luck!

**EDIT:** looks like someone gave you the answer. You should really understand **why** it may or may not meet your needs. Additionally, using tabs (`"\t"`) may or may not meet your (or your requestor's) requirements. If the spacing of the columns matter, you may want to look back at my answer.

Comment: ya the answer provided works up until the digits get larger like if the input was 40. I'm trying to figure it out at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this;

Use tab characters to separate most digits, and print a newline every fourth digit, and use num in the for loop terminating condition instead of 10.

```
if (1 <= num && num <= 40) {
    /* Add this to print the first two fibinacci values */
    printf("\t1\t1");        
    for(i=2;i<num;){
        n = f1 + f2;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = n;
        printf("\t%d",n);
        /* Once we've printed 4 digits print a newline */
        if (++i%4==0)
            printf("\n");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can play with it.

```
printf(i % 4 == 0 ? "\t%d\t\n" : "\t%d\t", n);
```